# get parent object from button click

Tags: java, android, layout, view

i got a custom class which inflates its layout from a xml. within that xml i got a button. 
then in my activity i instanziate that custom class and add it to:

1. a linear layout (the view of the custom class)
2. a typed array (the hole object)

now i want that if the button is pressed the object gets removed from both, the typed array and the layout. 
now my problem is that first i got two places where i have to remove the object and second that i cant find a way to "find" the object in the typed array. the button only returns its view. using .parent.parent till i reach the view of the custom class' view i'm able to remove it from the layout but there dosn't seem to be a way to get a reference to the object itself from the buttonpress.

maybe the hole concept how i'm doing it is wrong, dunno. hope you can help.

**EDIT: to clearify abit**

MActivity:

```
public class MActivity extends Activity{
private ArrayList<MCustomObject> objList = new ArrayList<MCustomObject>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout;

    MCustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject(this, "blabla1");
    objList.add(obj1);
    MCustomObject obj2 = new CustomObject(this, "blabla2");
    objList.add(obj2);
    MCustomObject obj3 = new CustomObject(this, "blabla3");
    objList.add(obj3);
    }
}
```

MCustomObject:

```
public class MCustomObject{

public MCustomObject(Context context, String xyz){
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.m_custom_object_layout, null);

button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mButton);

[...]
```

m_custom_object_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now when i press mButton i want that the hole obj instanz that the button belongs to gets deleted from the objList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my second answer written after you've added more details in your question. First one is still valid but doesn't really apply to your situation. What I suggest is put the code for your button in the original activity, by using the one you're already passing as a callback. Something like:

```
public class MCustomObject{
    private final String customId;

    public MCustomObject(final MActivity parent, final String customId, String xyz){ 
        this.customId = customId;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.m_custom_object_layout, null);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // do your other stuff
               parent.removeCustomObject(customId);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getId() {
        return customId;
    }
```

I changed the context parameter type to `MActivity` (and made it `final` because it's used in an anonymous class). If you need the possibility to build your `MCustomObject` from multiple activities (not only `MActivity`, then I suggest you extract out the `removeCustomObject` method into an interface, and you make all the activities implement it.

And in your `MActivity`, you add the following methods:

```
public void removeCustomObject(String customId) {
    objList.remove(findCustomObjectWithId(id));
}

private MCustomObject findCustomObjectWithId(int id) {
    for(MCustomObject custom : objList) {
        if (custom.getId() == id) {
            return custom;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

(NB: replacing your list `objList` with a

```
Map<String, MCustomObject>
```

in which you map customIds to objects would make the lookup easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
View.getId()
```

to find the button in your array.

```
for(int i =0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if(button.getId() == array.get(i).getId())
    /* Found! */ 
}
```

Comment: I don't think the button is in the array, he's talking of a custom view. But I agree with the method to of get something out of the array.

Comment: well, i'm talking about the custom object to be exact. i dont know if its a view. it is a simple java class which inflates its layout from a xml. does that make it to a view?

Comment: It should inherit from `View` or something else that inherits from `View` class.

Comment: that would be possible, but i don't allways want to inherit from view just to get object references.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LAS_VEGAS user, 
when you create buttons you should set button id (button.id= ) and you can point them by

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v.getId ==  )
    {
          //whatever you want
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want the button to be removed but the hole custom class that contains the button.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I suggest using an ArrayList instead of a simple array, as it has better support for things like remove, etc.
Some context is missing to give you a full solution (how to decide with `viewId` you want to remove?), but that should get you going.

```
private List<Custom> myListOfCustom = new ArrayList<Custom>();
// initialize myListOfCustom the way you want by using myListOfCustom.add(object)

// button clicked
public void buttonClicked(View v) {
    final int id = ...; // obtain id here
    myListOfCustom.remove(findCustomObjectWithId(id));
    // also remove the view from your layout
}

private Custom findCustomObjectWithId(int id) {
    for(Custom custom : myListOfCustomObjects) {
        if (custom.getId() == id) {
            return custom;
        }
    }
    return null; // custom object with givenm id was not in the list! alternatively, you can throw a RuntimeException here (something like an IllegalArgumentException) and catch it in the buttonClicked method
}
```

Comment: well i'm not sure if that helps. like i said i got that custom object which basicly is a instanz of a simple java class which itself uses the inflate method to get a layout from a xml. does that make the hole class to a view? or do i have to search for the <customobject> type? if so, how do i get a reference to the <customobject> type instead of only a reference to its view?

Comment: I thought your custom object was extending View, as you said it "inflates its layout from an XML". Well, if it's a custom object, you need some way to identify it, why not having an id field on it? I've edited my example to rename it to Custom (not View), but the idea is the same...

Comment: Also, if you added some code in your question, getting specific help would be a lot easier

Comment: code added. as you see the custom object is not extending view. its only using the inflate method. i dont know if that's the same.

Comment: Ok. What prevents you from giving an id to your CustomObjects, and a method to retrieve it? MCustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject(this, "id_of_this_object", "blabla1"), and then a public String getId(). And you can even replace your List with a HashMap<id, custom object>. So now I know a bit more, I'd do it otherwise. I'm writing another answer for it.